# Call external API (curl like) from PIG scripting language

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I am new to pig scripting and want to know what all I can do with it. I understand that pig is more like sql which helps you to fetch data and manipulate it but is there any way I can call external service or API to fetch the data and process it along with the data fetched from pigStorage() or cassandraStorage() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig isn't so much a peer to SQL as it is a scripting language that quietly provides abstractions to a number of common mapreduce patterns... But that's splitting hairs.  If you want to do something like call an external service then the way to do that would be to write (or reuse) an eval UDF function.  There are several kinds of UDF's and they are essentially exits into Java that let you code your functions any way you see fit.

Be careful, though. A call to an external service, performed once for each tuple, might take way too much time.  If the external calls are few in number then an eval UDF function might work.  If you want to make these calls for a large number of tuples then consider using an InputFormatType and a LOAD UDF to read the external data all at once and then join it with your original data using the regular pig operators and statements.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Chris. I will definitely try this. We are making use tracking service, to collect users view, asked and all than we want to process data based on the groups uses belongs to. We are not storing group information as we are thinking of fetching that information while running the map reduce job. Hope it works

Comment: Hi Chris, I am writing my custom UDF and extedning LoadFunc, but its looks like 1) it needs some file path which tells load data from, but I want to call endpoint not file 2) does it internally tries to split the data ? which in my case is not true. 3) should i consider EvalFunc but I want to load all the data from endpoint at once. so I am confused what should be done. 4) It give me "ERROR 2118: No input paths specified in job" what should i pass as in Job?